# Is ViewData the new standard over ViewBag for ASP.Net 5 (core)?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have noticed that in all the examples and tutorials on ASP.Net 5 (core) I have seen from Microsoft and the default Web Application template in VS 2015 use `@ViewData["XXX"]` instead of `@ViewBag.XXX`. Is this the, now, recommended way of passing data up from the controller instead of `ViewBag`? I know that `ViewBag` is a wrapper for `ViewData` but in the old tutorials (ASP.NET 4.5) they use `ViewBag`. If they are now encouraging developers to use `ViewData` why the change?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Both are still valid. There is no specific guidance on the [docs.asp.net github project](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/contribute/style-guide.html). Although there is [this discussion](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/803) on docs.asp.net issues.

That links through to [a comment](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2392) from one the product team which says:

> "Since ViewData (Dictionary) look-ups far out-perform ViewBag
>   (dynamic) invocations, the last is probably the best choice."

So I'd say it purely a style choice based upon the fact that ViewData performs better.

Comment: Thanks this perfectly answers my question. I think I will be using `ViewData` my self.